# Angular Telerik Kendo Grid Not displaying Data beyond first level

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, grid, hierarchical-data

We're using Kendo Grid on Angular 5 project.

In html, we have:

For kendo-grid-column field="Property-A.Code" - Works

But kendo-grid-column field="Property-B.Property-B-One.CodeName" - does NOT Work

How can one access data that is 2 levels down in hierarchy?

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure property names are valid JavaScript identifiers, apart from this you should be able to bind both two and three levels of nested data, e.g.:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="Category.CategoryName" width="200" title="Category - II level">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Category.nested.foo" width="200" title="Test - III level">
        </kendo-grid-column>

public gridData: any[] = [
{
    "ProductID": 1,
    "ProductName": "Chai",
    "SupplierID": 1,
    "CategoryID": 1,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "10 boxes x 20 bags",
    "UnitPrice": 18,
    "UnitsInStock": 39,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 0,
    "ReorderLevel": 10,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "Category": {
        "CategoryID": 1,
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Description": "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales",
        nested: {
          foo: 'bar'
        }
    },
    "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 8, 20)
},
{
    "ProductID": 2,
    "ProductName": "Chang",
    "SupplierID": 1,
    "CategoryID": 1,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "24 - 12 oz bottles",
    "UnitPrice": 19,
    "UnitsInStock": 17,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 40,
    "ReorderLevel": 25,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "Category": {
        "CategoryID": 1,
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Description": "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales",
        nested: {
          foo: 'baz'
        }
    },
    "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 7, 12)
}];
```

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/WIG9iLz8AOzychC3slla?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. We had an issue with data relationships with child data.

Thanks for your assistance. Your code is indeed how to get to multi-level data